# React keeps loading when using Bootstrap <Nav.Link>

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

When I use the following code for a navbar without any links, React started up fine and displays the navbar.

```
function Nav() {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

However, when I add links using <Nav.Link> React just keeps loading and I can't even right-click to view the console.

```
function Nav() {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
        <Nav className="me-auto">
          <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this before:

1. Make sure you have installed `react-bootstrap`.
2. Make sure you have imported the required components like here `import { Navbar, Container, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";`
3. Make sure you are exporting the same using `export default <component_name>`.

I have restructured your code as

```
<Navbar bg="dark" expand="lg" variant="dark">
  <Container>
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
      <Nav className="me-auto">
        <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
```

[image: screenshot]

Also like to suggest you to explore `react-router` to enable single page loading.
[Link](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: Thanks. However, I found the problem. It was because my component was also called Nav. Once I change the component to TopNav it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by changing to component name:

```
 import { Navbar, Container, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
    
    function TopNav() {
      return (
        <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
          <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="me-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
      );
    }
```